# mariadb python - executemany using SELECT

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, executemany

Im trying to input many rows to a table in a mariaDB.
For doing this i want to use executemany() to increase speed.
The inserted row is dependent on another table, which is found with SELECT.
I have found statements that SELECT doent work in a executemany().
Are there other ways to sole this problem?

```
import mariadb

connection = mariadb.connect(host=HOST,port=PORT,user=USER,password=PASSWORD,database=DATABASE)
cursor = connection.cursor()
  
query="""INSERT INTO [db].[table1] ([col1], [col2] ,[col3])
VALUES ((SELECT [colX] from [db].[table2] WHERE [colY]=? and
[colZ]=(SELECT [colM] from [db].[table3] WHERE [colN]=?)),?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
[col2]= ?,
[col3] =?;"""

values=[input_tuplets]
```

When running the code i get the same value for `[col1]` (the SELECT-statement) which corresponds to the values from the from the first tuplet.

If SELECT doent work in a executemany() are there another workaround for what im trying to do?
Thx alot!

Comment: Can you please provide a short reproducible example with parameters and preferable not in MSSQL emulation mode?

Comment: Thx for your respond @GeorgRichter.
Ill put a reproducable (silly) example below.
The example works when its not in emulation mode.
I also works a single query in emulation mode. The issue is when the command `execute_many()` is used.
One way aound this would be to find another way of doing this without using select. Any ideas?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE region (id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,id_country INT(6),region VARCHAR(30))`

`CREATE TABLE countries (id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, country VARCHAR(30))`

`insert into countries (country) values ("ger"),("fra")`

`insert into region (region,id_country) values ("sounth",(select id from countries where country="ger"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that reading out the tables needed,
doing the search in python,
use exeutemany() to insert all data.
It will require 2 more queries (to read to tables) but will be OK when it comes to calculation time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your first question on stackoverflow which identified a bug in MariaDB Server.

Here is a simple script to reproduce the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int);
CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE t1;
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1),(2);
```

Python:

```
>>> cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO t1 VALUES \
    (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=?))", [(1,),(2,)])
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT a FROM t1")
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[(1,), (1,)]
```

I have filed an [issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30523) in MariaDB Bug tracking system.

As a workaround, I would suggest reading the country table once into an array (according to Wikipedia there are 195 different countries) and use these values instead of a subquery.

e.g.

```
countries= {}
cursor.execute("SELECT country, id FROM countries")
for row in cursor:
  countries[row[0]]= row[1]
```

and then in executemany

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO region (region,id_country) values ('sounth', ?)", [(countries["fra"],) (countries["ger"],)])
```

Comment: thx for your comment Georg!
And, also for filing the bug.
The suggensted workaround is the one i tried to explain in my own comment, so thats good.
Thx alot!