# BatchUpdateException for batch size other than 1

Tags: sql, spring, maven, jdbc, mariadb

We recently updated our database to mariadb 10, but ever since the update I get an error when I try to Insert into the db, with the error of duplicate entry on one of our unique key constraint and I use the ON DUPLICATE KEY in my sql script.

For inserting I use a class that extends BatchSqlUpdate, but in that class I only set the data source, the insert sql, the batch size = 100 and use declareParameter() to set the sql parameters.

However we found a workaround if we change the batch size 1, the code works perfectly so I think it's might not caused by my code, but we need a proper solution and I'm out of ideas.

Currently I use:

- Mariadb 10.11.4 that runs on a server in a docker container
- mariadb-java-client 3.0.8
- spring-jdbc 5.3.28
- spring-data-jpa 2.5.7

```
INSERT INTO table(ldb, lid, scid, sid, valid)
VALUES(?, ?, (SELECT id FROM cserver WHERE ldb=? AND lid=?), ?, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY id=LAST_INSERTED_ID(id),
ldb=?, lid=? scid=(SELECT id FROM cserver WHERE ldb=? AND lid=?), sid, valid=1;
```

I have tried to read through the code and debug through it. Some advice said that it might was caused by the libraries so I tried to change some dependencies, but I can't change the spring-jdbc version to 6 or higher, and other changes didn't got me any results.

I would like to know what is the error. If it's caused by the db or the dependency or whatever at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mariadb python - executemany using SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260068/mariadb-python-executemany-using-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in MariaDB which was initially reported here on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260068/mariadb-python-executemany-using-select) and which is unfortunately still not fixed.

The subselect always returns the same value (see example in MDEV-30523) which results in your case in a duplicate key error.

MariaDB Bugtracker: [MDEV-30523](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30523)

Comment: Thanks for the help! This seems to be my problem too. I also forgot to add that I tried it with mariadb 11.0.3 running in docker, but the problem was still present in that version.

Comment: I tried to remove the subselect from the query to workaround the bug and executed the subselect query elsewhere, but I still get duplicate key error.

Comment: encountered the same.